# Generating all the increasing subsequences

Tags: python, list, sequence, dynamic-programming

Given an array of integers, how can we generate all the increasing subsequences such that all of them have same length ?

Example: given this list

```
l = [1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 6]
```

The answer should be if we consider subsequences of length 4:

```
[1, 2, 3, 6]
[1, 2, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 4, 6]
[1, 2, 5, 6]
[1, 4, 5, 6]
[2, 4, 5, 6]
```

```
from itertools import combinations

# the second item of the tuple is the position of the element in the array
zeta = [(1, 1), (2, 2), (4, 3), (5, 4), (3, 5), (6, 6)]
comb = combinations(sorted(zeta, key=lambda x: x[0]), 4)


def verif(x):
    l = []
    for k in x:
        l.append(k[1])
    for i in range(len(l)-1):
        if l[i+1]-l[i] < 0:
            return 0
    return 1


for i in comb:
    if verif(list(i)):
        print(i)
```

I want a better approach like dynamic programming solution, because obviously my solution is very slow for bigger list of integers. Is [LIS problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) helpful in this situation?

Comment: Is the input data like your zeta list?  What are some of the dimensions of the data set?

Comment: The input is a list , like L = [ 1 , 2 , 4 , 5 , 3 , 6 ] , I converted  it to zeta with tuples to match with my reasoning , i think this link will help in order to more understand the problem [LIS] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence)